# Using a loop to cut and paste Cells under conditions

Tags: vba, loops

I have a simple loop I want to use to cut and paste cells under conditions from one sheet to another one.

```
        Dim i, b As Long     

           For b=1 To 18 Step 2 
              For i = 5 To 21
                INTP = Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 18+b)
                client = Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 17+b)
                If IsNumeric(INTP) Then
                 Sheets("Feuil2").Columns(b).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = client
                 End If
               Next i
             Next b
```

With that code the problem is that only the value when i=21 will be paste in my next sheet (Feuil2). Nothing happen for the other values ...

I cannot figure what I am missing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are overwriting the values on top of each other, therefore only showing the last one (21).
Try replacing

```
Sheets("Feuil2").Columns(b).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = client
```

with

```
Sheets("Feuil2").cells(frow,2)=client
frow=frow+1
```

and add

```
dim frow as integer
frow=1 '' or the first empty row in your list
```

to top of your sub